# How do you use sendMultimediaMessage in Android SmsManager to send MMS?

Tags: android, sms, mms

I'm having a hard time sending MMS with `sendMultimediaMessage()`. Do I need to provide the configOverrides parameter? And if so what should that parameter include?

I can send regular texts with the `sendTextMessage()` method without any problems, just the mms that doesnt work.

[Here is the method docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: Did you find a way to use `sendMultimediaMessage()` for MMS? I'm trying to do the same